# Is there a way to calculate a server's uptime with regards to hibernation?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, server, uptime

I'm on an ubuntu server, and when I run `uptime -p`, I see the following:

```
up 1 week, 5 days, 11 hours, 37 minutes
```

This is not accurate though, because there was a period that the machine was in hibernation.
How can I calculate the uptime starting from the hibernation wake till now?